# discord.py overwrite in create_text_channel permissions

Tags: python, discord, embed, discord.py, ejabberd-hooks

```
overwrites = {
    guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
    guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
}

channel = await guild.create_text_channel('secret', overwrites=overwrites
```

i want to add guild.(user id) and has permission to read message true ,please help if you know how to do this I need it to just add a specific user using the user id

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member) to get the `Member` object:

```
overwrites = {
    guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
    guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
    guild.get_member(id): discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
}
```