# Set Permissions of created channel Discord.PY

Tags: python, permissions, discord

So i want to add a bug report command to my bot and this is my Code:

```
@client.command()
async def bug(ctx):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    BugChannel = await guild.create_text_channel(f'bugreport {ctx.author.name}')
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} Describe your Bug in <#{BugChannel.id}>')
```

I want that only the author and ppl with a specific role can view the BugChannel

Comment: Is this helping you? [discord.py overwrite in create_text_channel permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63382181/discord-py-overwrite-in-create-text-channel-permissions)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a text channel with a dict of permissions.
You can read more about it in the [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_text_channel).

For your example it would be:

```
overwrites = {
    guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=False),
    ctx.author: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True),
    your_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True)
}
channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(f'bugreport {ctx.author.name}', overwrites=overwrites)
```

So the key of the dict is a [Role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#role) or a [User](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#id7) and the Value a [PermissionOverwrite](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#permissionoverwrite).

And you also should just use `ctx.guild` insetad of `ctx.message.guild`